# pyinstaller not importing submodules

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I cannot seem to get pyinstaller to correctly package a module.

**Example module structure**

```
myapp/
      __main__.py
      mysubmodule.py
```

**Example `__main__.py` content**

```
"""My __main__.py."""

import myapp.mysubmodule

print("Done")
```

If I run `python -m myapp` it runs with no errors and prints `Done`.

If I run `pyinstaller myapp` I get errors stating it's a directory.

If I run `pyinstaller myapp/__main__.py` it builds but when I execute the `dist/__main__/__main__` which is generated I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myapp'`.

How can I get pyinstaller to include `myapp` as a module so it can be imported?

Comment: Any specific reason to not just `import mysubmodule` in `__main__.py`?

Comment: Interestingly if I do that `python -m myapp` stops working but the built version starts working.

Comment: Weird. Just as an experiment, does relative `from . import mysubmodule` work?

Comment: No with a relative import I get `ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package`

Comment: Right, makes total sense.

Comment: What about a separate entry file? Outside of the package?

Comment: Figured it out! Turns out pyinstaller ignores virtualenv, so it was building a python3 application with python2, the import error was a red herring caused by other issues. Fixed by reinstalling pyinstaller with pip3 globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `__init__.py` otherwise `myapp` it is not a valid module/package.

The missing file is:

- `myapp/__init__.py`

**EDIT:**

You can leave `__init__.py` empty.

Read the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html).

> The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In the simplest case, `__init__.py` can just be an empty file, but it can also execute initialization code for the package or set the `__all__` variable, described later.

Comment: Not necessary since Python 3.3+ I believe

Comment: tell this to pylint and pyinstaller they don't care about this.

Comment: @SzabolcsDombi The toy example I posted above does start working, however my actual application doesn't. I'll tweak the above to be more representative.

Comment: Add `__init__.py` for every folder.

Comment: I commented my solution above, however it's pretty specific to my issue. I'm going to accept this answer as it solves the toy example I used in the question.